# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) al intentar descargar datos de Yahoo Finance

Tags: python

Alguien tiene idea de por que no se puede bajar datos de la API de yahoo? simplemente manda un error. Desde el día de ayer lo noté, Habrá que actualizar? el código es el siguiente:

```
import yfinance as yf
tick="AAPL"
start='2021-01-01'
end='2021-06-30'
df=yf.download(tick,start, end, progress=False)
```

y siempre me manda el siguiente error

```
df=yf.download("AAPL","2021-01-01","2021-06-30",progress=False)
Exception in thread Thread-55:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\INGE. EDMUNDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\INGE. EDMUNDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Finance2\venv\lib\site-packages\multitasking\__init__.py", line 102, in _run_via_pool
    return callee(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Finance2\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 167, in _download_one_threaded
    data = _download_one(ticker, start, end, auto_adjust, back_adjust,
  File "C:\Python\Finance2\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\multi.py", line 179, in _download_one
    return Ticker(ticker).history(period=period, interval=interval,
  File "C:\Python\Finance2\venv\lib\site-packages\yfinance\base.py", line 157, in history
    data = data.json()
  File "C:\Python\Finance2\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\INGE. EDMUNDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\INGE. EDMUNDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\INGE. EDMUNDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Espero alguien sepa que pasa.

Comment: cual es el error? como traes los datos? que versión utilizas (de python y del módulo de yahoo)?. [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/468700/edit) tu pregunta añadiendo más detalles

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, ¿tienes conexión a internet? ¿tu API Key es válida?, etc, etc. etc. Faltan muchos detalles para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Desde luego que tiene que ver con la programación, yo tengo en mi código import yfinance as y y luego uso la sentencia df=yf.download(parametros) y siempre me manda error, probablemente a alguien le este pasando y puede darme la solución

Comment: @CandidMoe ??? si tiene que ver con programación °-°

Comment: hace unos días hubo una pregunta similar y no pude replicar su problema, que versión de python tienes??

Comment: bueno, no siempre la falla está en el código, pero espero puedan ayudar a este pobre newbie, así como yo estoy ayudando a otros, soy nuevo pero ya he empezado a responder, debido a que es mi regla, por cada pregunta que hago respondo tres

Comment: La OP original sólo contenía texto, no código. Suponiendo que el código está bueno, entonces el problema está en Yahoo FInance (manda mal la información), ergo -> no es un problema de programación.

Comment: ohhh es verdad, uso pyCharm y tengo la 3.9 sin embargo el codigo lo hice en 3.8 tendrá que ver?

Comment: corrigiendo `start='2021-01-0'` a `start='2021-01-01'` todo me funciona correctamente

Comment: Si el codigo de las fechas esta bien, solo en la pregunta lo puse mal, péro si si anda, seguramente es la versión de python, intentaré en el VENV usar el 3.8

Comment: lo probé usando Python 3.7.10

Comment: Pfff que frustacion, use 3.8 y sigue falllando, incluso ahora lo hice desde el path, bueno intentaré con esa versión

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 4):

He notado últimamente que muchas personas tienen problemas con el módulo `yfinance`. Para dar respuestas rápidamente no utilizo mi editor de código, sino que utilizo la plataforma de [Google colaboratory](http://colab.research.google.com/), tiene una interfaz muy parecida a Jupyter Notebook y es muy bueno para codificar. En tal plataforma no he podido recrear el problema, siempre me funcionaba.

```py
tick="AAPL"
start='2021-01-01'
end='2021-06-30'
df=yf.download(tick,start, end, progress=False)
```

Teniendo un resultado truncado:

| Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-01-04 | 133.520004 | 133.610001 | 126.760002 | 129.410004 | 128.997803 |
| 2021-01-05 | 128.889999 | 131.740005 | 128.429993 | 131.009995 | 130.592697 |
| 2021-01-06 | 127.720001 | 131.050003 | 126.379997 | 126.599998 | 126.196747 |
| 2021-01-07 | 128.360001 | 131.630005 | 127.860001 | 130.919998 | 130.502991 |
| 2021-01-08 | 132.429993 | 132.630005 | 130.229996 | 132.050003 | 131.629379 |

En Google colab no viene instalado el módulo `yfinance` por lo que se tiene que instalar, eso significa que cada vez que se quiera ejecutar el programa se descargará el módulo más reciente disponible, al hacer `pip show yfinance` se obtiene:

```
Name: yfinance
Version: 0.1.63
Summary: Yahoo! Finance market data downloader
....
```

Donde se aprecia que la versión descargada y utilizada al momento de escribir este post es `0.1.63`, cosa que no detalla la pregunta, si crees que el problema proviene de las versiones, debes añadirlo a tu pregunta, esto es parte de un ejemplo mínimo verificable, ya que es una característica para replicar el problema. Otro factor es la versión de Python utilizada, el backend (o CPU) de Google utiliza `Python 3.7.10` que tampoco detalla la pregunta.

Voy a dejar el [cuaderno de Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Wakgv2P-BtEFiLGXtY2CR95yQc6mahmV?usp=sharing) para que puedan probar que todo esto funciona, si algo ha cambiado déjame un comentario y lo revisaré o daré acceso para modificar el cuaderno.

Bueno y que puedes hacer?, lo que han detallado las otras respuesta es correcto, ya que al final es lo se hace en Google Colab, pero también puedes hacer otra cosa, por ejemplo descargar otra versión de Python (anterior) y crear un entorno virtual para poder trabajar correctamente. También puedes visitar la [documentación de yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) y/o verificar los [issues existentes](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/)

Siempre se recomienda trabajar con una versión anterior a la que recientemente salió, pues muchos paquetes, módulos o herramientas tardan bastante tiempo en actualizar sus herramientas para que funcionen correctamente con la versión reciente, muchas veces demoran años, por tal razón se recomienda trabajar con una versión anterior para no tener problemas. Y siempre procura trabajar en un entorno virtual :)

Answer (score 1):

al parecer es un problema común, me paso el día de ayer y lo único que hice fui a instalarla de nuevo.

Este es el comando para desinstalar.

```
pip uninstall -y yfinance
```

y para instalarla de nuevo.

```
pip install yfinance
```

De hecho en la [documentación de Github](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/) que te contestaron anteriormente viene este problema descrito.

Answer (score 0):

Yo desinstalé y volví a instalar yfinance y se corrigió el error.

```
pip uninstall -y yfinance
```

Luego

```
pip install yfinance
```

Comment: ¿Te fijaste si la versión que instalaste es una versión más reciente que la que tenías anteriormente? Eso es clave dado este [issue en el repositorio de yfinance en Github](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/777).

Comment: 0.1.63 es la versión instalada

Comment: Amigos gracias por su fantástica ayuda!!!!!! ha quedado listo mi código y corriendo