# ¿Ya no es posible acceder a Yahoo Finanzas?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Desde hace unas semana, no puedo acceder a Yahoo Finanzas, de diferentes maneras, con script que siempre me funcionaron bien. Todas las opciones me devuelven errores, muy largos para transcribirlos en esta consulta.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime as dt

start = "2017-1-4"
end = "2021-5-12"
IBE = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)
IBE[:3]
```

Error devuelto

```
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_5363/2775007848.py in <module>
      5 start = "2017-1-4"
      6 end = "2021-5-12"
----> 7 IBE = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)
      8 IBE[:3]

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, api_key)
    374 
    375     if data_source == "yahoo":
--> 376         return YahooDailyReader(
    377             symbols=name,
    378             start=start,

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in read(self)
    251         # If a single symbol, (e.g., 'GOOG')
    252         if isinstance(self.symbols, (string_types, int)):
--> 253             df = self._read_one_data(self.url, params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
    254         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
    255         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151         url = url.format(symbol)
    152 
--> 153         resp = self._get_response(url, params=params)
    154         ptrn = r"root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);"
    155         try:

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _get_response(self, url, params, headers)
    179             msg += "\nResponse Text:\n{0}".format(last_response_text)
    180 
--> 181         raise RemoteDataError(msg)
    182 
    183     def _get_crumb(self, *args):

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBE.MC/history?period1=1483498800&period2=1620871199&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n  <html lang="en-us"><head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n      <meta charset="utf-8">\n      <title>Yahoo</title>\n      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimal-ui">\n      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">\n      <style>\n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      </style>\n  <script>\n    document.write(\'<img src="//geo.yahoo.com/b?s=1197757129&t=\'+new Date().getTime()+\'&src=aws&err_url=\'+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+\'&err=%<pssc>&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>\');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+new Date().getTime()+"&src=aws&err_url="+encodeURIComponent(document.URL)+"&err=%<pssc>&test="+encodeURIComponent(\'%<{Bucket}cqh[:200]>\');\n  </script>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n  <!-- status code : 404 -->\n  <!-- Not Found on Server -->\n  <table>\n  <tbody><tr>\n      <td>\n      <img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_frontpage_en-US_s_f_p_205x58_frontpage.png" alt="Yahoo Logo">\n      <h1 style="margin-top:20px;">Will be right back...</h1>\n      <p id="message-1">Thank you for your patience.</p>\n      <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p>\n      </td>\n  </tr>\n  </tbody></table>\n  </body></html>'
```

¿Han dejado de permitir las descargas?.

Comment: Si no nos cuenta cual es el error no tenemos por donde empezar.

Comment: Por alguna razón a mi me deja

Comment: En el error que pasas el [html](https://jsfiddle.net/rkczeuo8/) dice que hay un problema y que sus ingenieros están en ello

Comment: Ya llevan dos semanas. Para mi es un contratiempo grande ya que mis desarrollos los tengo basados en descargas de Yahoo.

Comment: Dice Christian que a él le deja. ¿Podría ser un problema de mi suministrador de Internet?

Comment: Versiones instaladas: python 3.8.10 e yfinance 0.1.59

Comment: Chistian, agradeceré nos pongas en esta consulta el enlace que hace un momento me has puesto . La he abierto, leído y al cerrarla esperando verla más tarde con más detalle, he perdido el acceso a la misma. Quiero revisar todo lo que en ella indicas.

Comment: hola!, disculpa recien veo tu comentario (es preferible que me menciones @ mi nombre) que deseas que te pase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este enlace a una respuesta a esta pregunta, realizada por [@Christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian) es muy útil: [jsondecodeerror expecting value line 1 column 1 char 0 al-intentar-descargar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/468700/jsondecodeerror-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-al-intentar-descargar/469061#469061)

De las opciones que plantea, trabajar en Google Colaboraty te obliga a dearrollar ahí todo el código y prescindir de tu jupyter y de la privacidad de tu script. Por otro lado, el hecho de que tengo instalado python 3.8.10 e yfinance 0.1.59, creo que en mi caso,puede ser la razón del fallo. La opción posible es trabajar creando un entorno nuevo con las revisiones que se sabe funcionan en Google Colaboraty (python 3.7.10 e yfinance 0.1.63), o esperar a que Yahoo adapte su ISO a esta revisión de python 3.8.10.

He probado en un entorno virtual con python 3.8. e yfinance 1.4.0 y me importa bien.