# Dada una gráfica obtenida de un DataFrame, ¿Cómo podríamos en python calcular la pendiente de la tangente a la curva en uno de sus puntos)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

No me funciona Yahoo Finances, por lo que recurro a esta opción para facilitaros la base de datos de la consulta.
Descargamos un fichero csv con cotizaciones de un valor, de la siguiente manera.

```
https://stooq.com/q/d/l/?s=^IBEX&i=d
```

Graficamos los valores.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/home/enri/Descargas/ibex35.csv', header=0, sep=',')
df[["Close"]].plot()
```

¿Cómo podría calcular el valor de la tangente a la curva en uno cualquiera de sus puntos?.

La función gradient de numpy, ¿serviría para lo mismo?.

Comment: puedes leer la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/469061/183782) que hice, si no te funciona yfinance

Comment: para calcular la pendiente se hace con `y = mx + b` solo tendrías que reemplazar los valores segun lo que necesites

Comment: Christian, el problema es que no conocemos la ecuación de la recta. Ese es el problema, Cómo deducir la ecuación de la tangente en un punto a esa curva.

Comment: halla la función de correspondencia `m = (y1-y)/(x1-x)`

Comment: La función gradient de numpy, ¿serviría para lo mismo?.

Comment: creo que eso servía para hallar el valor mínimo (no estoy muy seguro)

Comment: Estoy pensando en calcular una media móvil y tratar de aplicar esa fórmula de la pendiente de una recta, considerando incrementos de 1 día en abscisas y la diferencia entre los  valores de la media móvil en esos puntos, como  ordenadas. Veré a ver si lo que me sale sirve para mi objetivo. Tendré que probar con diferentes medias móviles.

Comment: De todas formas, mediante cálculo diferencial con python, tiene que haber alguna manera de hacerlo. Lo que pasa es que mis matemáticas ya están un poco oxidadas.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127559/discussion-between-christian-and-efueyo).

Answer (score 2):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera (adaptado de @James Phillips [Compute and plot tangent lines along a curve produced by polynomial regression using np.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52458870/compute-and-plot-tangent-lines-along-a-curve-produced-by-polynomial-regression-u/68406763#68406763).

Una vez importada y filtrada la base de datos, selecciono y calculo una SMA Media Móvil Simple o una EMA Media Móvil Exponencial. Hago pruebas hasta obtener una curva suavizada, que sea de mi interés, de la curva del histórico de cotizaciones.

A continuación, la función `numpy.polyval(ParamterosAjustados,, ...)` calcula la ecuación de la curva, y la función `numpy.polyval(deriv, ...)` calcula la pendiente de la tangente a la curva en cada uno de sus puntos; almaceno estos valores en la columna `datos["pendientes"]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/home/enri/Descargas/ibex35.csv', header=0, sep=',')

datos = df[["Close"]].reset_index()

datos["SMA70"]=  datos["Close"].rolling(70).mean().dropna()

xData = numpy.array(datos.index)
yData = numpy.array(datos["SMA70"])

# Curva polinómica ajustada a los datos de las cotizaciones.
ParamterosAjustados = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, 3)

# valor de la derivada (pendiente ) en cada valor específico de x
datos["pendiente"] = 0
pendientes = []
i = 0
while i <= datos.shape[0]-1:
    valor_y_del_punto = numpy.polyval(ParamterosAjustados, datos.index[i])
    pendiente_en_el_punto = numpy.polyval(deriv, datos["Close"][i])
    pendientes.append(pendiente_en_el_punto)
    i+=1
    
datos["pendientes"] =  pendientes  

plt.plot(datos[["Close", "SMA70", "pendientes"]])
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado esta opción:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# preparación de datos
df = cotiz_val.copy(deep=True).reset_index()
df["indice"]= df.index 

coordinates = df.to_numpy()

# Derivada de la curva en cada punto
x_t = np.gradient(coordinates[:, 2])
y_t = np.gradient(coordinates[:, 1])

# cálculo de la velocidad de la curva en todos los puntos.
vel = np.array([ [x_t[i], y_t[i]] for i in range(x_t.size)])

# calculo de la rapidez como módulo de la velocidad. 
speed = np.sqrt(x_t * x_t + y_t * y_t)

# cálculo de la tangente
tangent = np.array([1/speed] * 2).transpose() * vel


# curvatura es una medida de la desviación de una curva respecto a una línea recta.
ss_t = np.gradient(speed)
xx_t = np.gradient(x_t)
yy_t = np.gradient(y_t)

curvature_val = np.abs(xx_t * y_t - x_t * yy_t) / (x_t * x_t + y_t * y_t)**1.5
```

Adaptado de: [curvature formula numpy](https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/numpy/curvature-formula-numpy/)